# Flask: URLs w/ Variable parameters

Tags: python, flask

I have a URL string I want to build in the following manner:

`http://something.com/mainsite/key1/key2/key3/keyn`

How would I generate something like this in my URL mapping where n is a variable number?

How would I get those keys?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Simply use the [`path` route converter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations):

   ```
   @app.route("/mainsite/<path:varargs>")
   def api(varargs=None):
       # for mainsite/key1/key2/key3/keyn
       # `varargs` is a string contain the above
       varargs = varargs.split("/")
       # And now it is a list of strings
   ```
2. Register your own [custom route converter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.url_map) (see [Werkzeug's documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#custom-converters) for the full details):

   ```
   from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter, ValidationError

   class PathVarArgsConverter(BaseConverter):
       """Convert the remaining path segments to a list"""

       def __init__(self, url_map):
           super(PathVarArgsConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
           self.regex = "(?:.*)"

       def to_python(self, value):
           return value.split(u"/")

       def to_url(self, value):
           return u"/".join(value)

   app.url_map.converters['varargs'] = PathVarArgsConverter
   ```

   which you can then use like this:

   ```
   @app.route("/mainsite/<varargs:args>")
   def api(args):
       # args here is the list of path segments
   ```