# flask with unknown uri routes

Tags: python, flask

I have several DB in SQLALCHEMY databases that provide a URI/query and a JSON output to my front end. The JSON is based upon YANG models.
If I use RFC8040 to iterate over my 'yang' model with a URI, then I can GET information from my specific object and return it. However, then I need to write all possible URI...

example

json:

```
{"person":{"name":"foo", "address"{"city":"Ghent", "postal_code":"9000}}}
```

My URI

```
/restconf/data/person/name 
   returns a list of db items
   {"person":
       {"name":["foo"]
       }
    }
```

This should return a list of items in the "name", then I can use name=foo to get that information of that filter.

Other URI

```
/restconf/data/person/address/postal_code  
returns list of db items
{"person":
   {"address":
       {"postal_code": ["9000"]
       }
   }
 }
```

What are the options to create a dynamic URL inside flask?
Or do I have to manually write all possible iterations? Can't it be done with a smarter solution?

something like:

```
@person_blueprint.route("/<*args>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def persontest(*args):
    return f"<h1>{*args}</h1>"
```

Objective:
In my example I use the flask blueprint, so my UR is pre-pended with /restconf/data/person.
I like to iterate over my JSON output with a 'dynamic' URI. So the client can iterate through the 'YANG' model and find results. The results help to filter on a specific object like: /postal_code="something"...

Comment: Is it similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602276/flask-urls-w-variable-parameters

Comment: okay thank you a lot - do I set solve here?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602276/flask-urls-w-variable-parameters is the answer to your question. However i would not suggest you do that.
You should use query arguments `flask.request.args` to pass the query parameters like `?name=foo&city=Ghent&postal_code=9000`.

Comment: Directly putting what you have in a URL into your SQL query is an invitation to SQL injection and malicious DB attacks.

Comment: I would suggest you use `flask.request.args` which is a dictionary you can access in your routs functions. Then use DTO tools (such as marshmallow) to convert into a dictionary with correct data types. Then use the much more secured result to form your database filter

Comment: @AlexanderK1987 SQLAlchemy should be completely safe from injection, not sure about malicious attacks though, would be interested to know how something could do damage from a select.